# How to apply int-function to vector-function

Tags: python

I recently learned about lambda and as assignment i have to write a function that:

1. only has a return statement in the function body
2. takes a  2 digit int-based function (such as x + y) and returns a functions that works on vectors.
   Here's what i have so far:

```
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass # the vector dataclass
class V3:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int

def map2(f: Any): # This takes a normal function and applies it to vector komponents
    return lambda f: lambda v,w:  V3(f(v.x, w.x), f(v.y, w.y), f(v.z, v.z))


def add(x: int, y: int): #This is a basic int functions to test out my other one
    return x + y

v1=(2,4,6)
v2=(3,5,7)
```

If i try map(add(v1,v2),i get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'V3' and 'V3'. What am i supposed to change so that i can add each component of the vector but not call the function out for each component as such?:

```
map2(add(v.x, w.x), add(v.y, w.y), add(v.z, w.z) #Not like this
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether you are asking for such functionality, but you could do the following:

```
def map2(f: Any): # This takes a normal function and applies it to vector komponents
    return lambda v,w:  V3(f(v.x, w.x), f(v.y, w.y), f(v.z, v.z))
```

This will return the callable taking v, w as arguments, and then apply it to the given vectors:

```
map2(add)(v1, v2)
```

Result is in your example:

```
V3(x=5, y=9, z=12)
```

Note, that `v1=(2,4,6)` is a `tuple`, I suppose you meant `v1=V3(2,4,6)`

Comment: Oh, I completely overlooked that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very generic way to do it that avoids hardcoding the class and attribute names into the code:

```
from typing import Any
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class V3:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int

    @property
    def vals(self):
        return tuple(getattr(self, field.name) for field in dataclasses.fields(self))


def map2(f: Any):
    return lambda a, b: type(a)(*map(f, a.vals, b.vals))

def add(x: int, y: int):
    return x + y

v1 = V3(2,4,6)
v2 = V3(3,5,7)

result = map2(add)(v1, v2)
print(result)  # -> V3(x=5, y=9, z=13)
```